# Blackberry facebook integration error

Tags: blackberry

I have integrated the facebook in my app using http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk, it work fine in stimulator but when view in device it show me the

```
http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=0000000000[0.0] 61&cancel=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%[0.0] 26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buse[0.0] r%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.re[0.0] quest%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D175269295861061%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fw[0.0] ww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26di[0.0] splay%3Dwap%26response_type%3Dtoken%26fbconnect%3D1%26perms%3Duser_about_me%252Cuser_activities%252C[0.0] user_birthday%252Cuser_education_history%252Cuser_events%252Cuser_groups%252Cuser_hometown%252Cuser_[0.0] interests%252Cuser_likes%252Cuser_location%252Cuser_not[0.0] es%252Cuser_online_presence%252Cuser_photo_video_tags%252Cuser_photos%252Cuser_relationships%252Cuse[0.0] r_relationship_details%252Cuser_religion_politics%252Cuser_status%252Cuser_videos%252Cuser_website%2[0.0] 52Cuser_work_history%252Cemail%252Cread_friendlists%252[0.0] Cread_insights%252Cread_mailbox%252Cread_requests%252Cread_stream%252Cxmpp_login%252Cads_management%[0.0] 252Cuser_checkins%252Cfriends_about_me%252Cfriends_activities%252Cfriends_birthday%252Cfriends_educa[0.0] tion_history%252Cfriends_events%252Cfriends_groups%252C[0.0] friends_hometown%252Cfriends_interests%252Cfriends_likes%252Cfriends_location%252Cfriends_notes%252C[0.0] friends_online_presence%252Cfriends_photo_video_tags%252Cfriends_photos%252Cfriends_relationships%25[0.0] 2Cfriends_relationship_details%252Cfriends_religion_pol[0.0] itics%252Cfriends_status%252Cfriends_videos%252Cfriends_website%252Cfriends_work_history%252Cmanage_[0.0] friendlists%252Cfriends_checkins%252Cpublish_stream%252Ccreate_event%252Crsvp_event%252Coffline_acce[0.0] ss%252Cpublish_checkins%252Cmanage_pages%252Coffline_ac[0.0] cess%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1&_rdr
```

I have change the app id in url.
just show me the text in white background.Please let me know if anything else requires.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what this URL is supposed to show us. What text is being displayed?

Comment: same url display on white screen and now also show the Access Token not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue from network side,i have check with other wi-fi and it was working.

Thank you.